# How can get Small image for Product?

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images

I have this code to show big image

```
$productImageUrl = $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$_product->getImage();
```

but how i can call URL for small img of product

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting your `$_product` object correctly then you can call below code to get **Small Product Image**.

```
$_product->getData('small_image');
```

Comment: they give me the same picture for product

Comment: print `$_product` object for small, thumbnail image URL and check that image inside `pub/media/catalog/product` folder. Also check that you have assigned correct image for that product.